# No sound playing after update from 16.04 to 18.04 on pinebook (ubuntu-MATE)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ppa, ubuntu-mate

Last week I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 on a pinebook with MATE desktop environment.  All works fine except one major problem and a few minor (?) issues which may or may not be related to the major problem (if unrelated I am happy to ignore).

Major problem: No sound plays through either speakers or headphones.  I have tried vlc (which throws a couple errors: `shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented`; `libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate`), `aplay -l` (which also throws the same `memfd` error as VLC), `speaker-test -c 2`, and the "test speakers" button in sound preferences. None make any sound.

Minor (?) issue 1: when I run `sudo apt-get update` I receive the errors `Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release 404 not found` and `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`

Minor (?) issue 2: when I run `pulseaudio -v` I receive the error `E: [pulseaudio] pid.c Daemon already running E: [pulseaudio] main.c pa_pid_create() failed`.

Minor (?) issue 3: when I run `pavucontrol` I again receive the error: `shared memfd open() failed: function not implemented`

After searching posts on similar errors, I have tried:

1. the basics: muting/unmuting, volume up/down, headphones in-out, rebooting
2. checking all channels are unmuted in `alsamixer`
3. updating/upgrading packages and fixing all broken links in synaptic package manager
4. `sudo alsa force-reload`
5. `sudo aptitude --purge-unused reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio`
6. `pulseaudio --kill sleep 2s; pulseaudio --start`
7. `killall -9 pulseaudio`
8. `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`
9. `rm ~/.pulse*` and `rm /tmp/pulse*`
10. Disabling speech-dispatcher
11. `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev`
12. `sudo gpasswd -a root audio`
13. `mv ~/.asoundrc ~/.asoundrc_old`

I am out of ideas and preparing to wipe and reinstall 16.04. Putting out a final call for suggestions before the nuclear solution.

System details:

```
$inxi -SMA
System:    Host: pinebook Kernel: 3.10.105-bsp-1.2-ayufan-59 aarch64 bits: 32
           Desktop: MATE 1.20.1  Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   No /sys/class/dmi; using dmidecode: no smbios data. Old system?
Audio:     Card-1 audiocodec driver: audiocodec
           Card-2 sndhdmi driver: sndhdmi
           Sound: ALSA v: k3.10.105-bsp-1.2-ayufan-59
```

In 'Sound Preferences' two hardware devices are listed: Analog Mono Output and Anolog Mono Duplex

Comment: Update: if anyone else runs in to this problem, a reinstall of 16.04 solved all issues.  Perhaps an unsatisfying fix, but easy and effective.